# Manage the PushViewController With Tabbar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have TabBar Embed-in in `SecondViewController` I have a tableview i want to push `ViewController` with the with `Didselect` And also back to the `secondViewController` with navigation Back Button.

> StoryBoardSetup

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create segues to navigation controllers for each transition you want with unique identifiers in storyboard.

Then you can call the transition manually in `didSelect` with `performSegue`:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Identifier", sender: self)
```

And because you embed your views in navigation controller you don't need to handle back button, it handles automatically.

Also you can set the next view controller properties by overriding the `perepareForSegue`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "Identifier") {
       let destination = segue.destination as! YourViewController
       // pass data to next view
    }
}
```